# How to go from Chita (Russia) to Manzhouli (China)?

Tags: trains, china, russia

I have booked the tickets up to Chita. After Chita, I want to go to Manzhouli (China). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to drive (that's still an option though) but you have the choice between flying or taking the train. According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Chita/Manzhouli)

## Fly

Both cities have airports and both Indonesian Airlines and Air China have a service between the two, though the airport in Chita is a little far from the center of town.

[image]

## Train

There's a train that leaves twice a week to China from Chita 2 station which is closer to the city than the airport. There's also a night train which interestingly enough seems to take less time, at least according to the website. It's operated by Russian railways

[image]
[image]